# Excel Custom Decimal Number Format Trailing Dot

Tags: excel, excel-2007, number-formatting

When I set custom number format `#0.####`, it works fine with whole numbers `123` & `123.23`, but it is not working with decimal numbers like `123.00`, as it is displaying this as `123.`

How can one set a correct number format so as not to display the `.` at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal number 123.00"? To Excel, 123.00 and 123 are the same number.

Comment: yes but that is problem.instead of displaying 123 it is displaying as 123.

Comment: You said "This is working fine with whole numbers (123)" but when I format `123` with `#0.####` it appears as `123.`

Comment: you missed .00,if i format 123.00 or 785.00 displaying as 123.,785.

Answer (score 5):

You can use conditional formatting to do this, in Excel 2007 and later, I believe. Format the cells with your custom format of `#0.####` as you've already done. Then add custom formatting to use the General Format if the cell value has no decimal portion.

In the Condtional Formatting dialog add a formula-based format. In the "Format values where this formula is true" box enter:

```
=INT(A2)=A2
```

In the Format Cells dialog click the Number tab and choose `General` as the format.

[image]

Comment: @Doug: Data is dynamic not sure which cell dont have decimal portion.How to do in this case.How to solve this in excel 2003 or excel 2007

Comment: Just do these for the whole range with your data. It's designed to work with your dynamic data. Go ahead and try it :). Your question is tagged Excel-2007 and that's what this works for. I don't think conditional formatting of number styles is available in 2003.

Comment: why nobody says is a Excel formatting bug, and should be fixed ?!! https://dotnetfiddle.net/5lXZ65

Answer (score 1):

`#` are optional digits to show. `0` will enforce that digit even if it is zero.  Make your number format `#0.00##`. This will display

- 123 as 123.00
- 123.00 as 123.00
- 123.000 as 123.00
- 123.001 as 123.001
- 123.001111 as 123.0011

Comment: :Thanks, I want to display 123 as 123 not 123.00

Comment: this should be reported as Excel bug, because normally, the #.### format is not respected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5lXZ65