# excel data formatting numbers

Tags: excel, number-formatting

My data coming from database and populating in excel but when my data looks like this `65.90` excel shows `65.9` and if I use formatting over it then I am facing issue : value `65` and it shows `65.00`

Comment: your desired format is should be XX.YY ?

Comment: but i want only 65 if the data is 65 not 65.00

Comment: so you don't want decimals

Comment: Edit → Format Cells → Numbers → Decimal Places: `0`

Comment: If you're using Excel 2007 or later [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180896/293078) might be of interest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A little more detail would be very helpful. Also, clarify the desired outcome for value of `65.90` and `65.00` since it's not really clear what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain leading or trailing zeros, format the cells as text.